# Flexbox, make all images equal width to fit inside a list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using WordPress and advanced custom fields, the user add or remove up to 10 images into a block. The images sit inline and must stay on one line.

The user is providing all sorts of width and height images and I can't rely on them to edit them carefully. These are client logos.

My aim is that all of the images in the list are auto resized so they all fit into the container but keep aspect ratio.

Any help?

Currently markup and CSS:

```css
.logo-list {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-list">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="SOURCE" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="SOURCE" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="SOURCE" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="SOURCE" alt="">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oc2r52n/4/)

Comment: simply specified a fixed height to image .. try this `.logo-list-image {
   height:80px;
}`

Comment: ..basically...NO I don't think you can. Not without changing the structure.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thats what I though, gone back to using inline block and and a wrapper around the images for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding just `flex: 1` to the `.logo-list-image` is enough to achieve the desired effect in Firefox, but that won't work in Chrome because of the well known *Flexbox layout issue* when scaling images.

So in order to make it work in Chrome, as well as in Firefox, you can do it with the `width: 100%` and `min-width: 0`, if you plan to use `align-items: center` on the *parent element*, but if you don't, you have to include `height: 100%` as well:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.logo-list {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* added */
}

.logo-list-image {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; include this if you don't plan to use align-items: center */ 
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-list">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://files.brightside.me/files/news/part_3/35405/656455-4-1-650-a542d8629a-1482214208.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Logo-Free.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhlpW2mlogSQxSGZ1a6fPpJMgRA5u8dvuqLOaz9GD8f3DPH_TF2w" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://files.brightside.me/files/news/part_3/35405/656455-4-1-650-a542d8629a-1482214208.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Logo-Free.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhlpW2mlogSQxSGZ1a6fPpJMgRA5u8dvuqLOaz9GD8f3DPH_TF2w" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

For image tags if you define one side then other side is resized to keep aspect ratio.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.logo-list {
    width:20%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.logo-list img{
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-list">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://files.brightside.me/files/news/part_3/35405/656455-4-1-650-a542d8629a-1482214208.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Logo-Free.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhlpW2mlogSQxSGZ1a6fPpJMgRA5u8dvuqLOaz9GD8f3DPH_TF2w" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://files.brightside.me/files/news/part_3/35405/656455-4-1-650-a542d8629a-1482214208.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Logo-Free.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="logo-list-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhlpW2mlogSQxSGZ1a6fPpJMgRA5u8dvuqLOaz9GD8f3DPH_TF2w" alt="">
</div>
```